# Using Shell Escape (!) in Simulink Model (MATLAB Function)

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to use a `MATLAB` function within Simulink to call a `Python` script using a shell escape function.

The only code within the `MATLAB` function file (.m file) is the following:

```
function y = fcn(u)    
%#codegen  
!C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Ben\Downloads\endrecording.py  
y = u;
```

When I try to execute this code I receive the following error:

Shell escape (!) is not supported.

```
Function 'MATLAB Function' (#35.30.92), line 3, column 1:
"!C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Ben\Downloads\endrecording.py"
Launch diagnostic report.
```

Is there another way to call this Python script without using Shell Escape, or possibly a workaround to get Shell Escape to work?

Comment: In recent version of MATLAB, it is possible to call python directly: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-defined-custom-module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [system](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function instead.

```
function y = fcn(u)    
%#codegen  
system('C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Ben\Downloads\endrecording.py')
y = u;
```

Also read [Run External Commands, Scripts, and Programs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up having to add a line at the beginning of the function: coder.extrinsic('system') , but otherwise it works perfectly.